# set default process and IO priority on Linux for given application/executable

Tags: linux, executable, priority

Is it possible to set up some sort of default process and IO priority for given application/executable? I am thinking some sort of FS extended attribute or loadable "policy" of sort?

Comment: What's wrong with `nice -19 ionice -c 3 command`?

Comment: @FloHimself I think @wilx is asking for some way of having the system automatically apply prorities to an executable whenever it is launched, without having to use `nice` or `ionice` every time.

Comment: @FloHimself: Yes, I want the policy to be automatically applied exactly like Stephen Kitt suggests.

Comment: The question should be expanded with some more background information. Why should this be done? What's the special use case?

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is to create a wrapper script.

Create a script `/usr/local/bin/nicer`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ionice -c3 nice /usr/bin/"${0##*/}" "$@"
```

Create symbolic links for each executable that you want to execute through this wrapper, e.g.

```
ln -s nicer /usr/local/bin/myprogram
```

Then when you run `myprogram`, it will execute the script `/usr/local/bin/myprogram`, which runs `/usr/bin/myprogram` with lower priorities.